# Should I add a comma in between 2 clauses to make it grammatically right?

Tags: commas

Here are my examples

**I would not wait but find the problem and fix it**

**I would not wait, but find the problem and fix it**

*Which one is correct?*

Answer (score 1):

I think a dash or a colon is required. A comma is not strong enough as the clauses are quite separate.
I would not wait**:** **I would** find the problem and fix it

I would not wait **- I would** find the problem and fix it

Comment: Neither of these is right. Is that what you mean?